# Finite distance propagation for charged particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, charge, neutrinos, propagator

Usually, when it comes to studying QFT at a finite distance, the underlying problem is neutrino oscillations. Could it be relevant in some sense to study finite-distance propagation of charged particles, e.g., electrons or W-bosons? Are there physical scenarios for which the account of finite space-time regions is important?

Comment: QFT is the formalism in terms of which particle physics is modeled. Neutrino oscillation would only play a role if the model under consideration is one that incorporates neutrinos.

Comment: Are you asking if there are flavor oscillations of charged particles? You know exactly how far a W will propagate freely before it decays, no? It is a function of its speed.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos  I'm not asking about the oscillations in particular, but rather about any setup where finite-distance methods are used with propagators of charged particles being involved.

Comment: You are asking about covariant perturbation theory in coordinate space? I have steered you to these methods, by Freedman et al, in the past, with stern & fair warning that they are difficult and unwieldy. But neutrino oscillations have *nothing* to do with them, and so you are alienating/misleading the reader right from the star. *Why* are you interested in them? You have been *told* they are ultra-messy.